# Solving problems with a given illustration, how do I proceed?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, illustration

I've been given this sample image, supposedly "pop art" style. What I'm asked are four steps:

```
1. reproduce this image
2. control the colors
3. add a two colors logo onto it
4. improve the overall image
```

**1. Reproduce this image**

[image: Demo Sample]

I'm at a good point and I used Filter `Gallery > Sketch > Halftone Pattern`, the result is not yet OK but quite close to it, I have set the level to `Linear Burn` and added a yellow background below it, I took the exact color from the image. **Edit**: Added a `Sharpen filter` it looks like below, still missing something but probably acceptable as "similar" image to the sample provided:

[image: My Latest Version]

**2. Control the Colors** *(Stuck Here)*

Aside than changing the below background layer I have found no means to alter the black "dots" added by the filter, probably there is another way of adding the pattern which allow more control?

**3. Add a Logo**

While this is simple, I just need to add two shapes and change the color with some that goes well with this yellow, I also need to reproduce various version of the background/square colors accordingly with the two colors of the logo, this step is the one that worries me the least.

**4. Improve the image**

I think it is too early to consider this aspect since Im stuck at points 1 and 2 to be honest, the image I get is "less polished" than the one I was given, a possibility to improve could be to add some blurr I think but it is too early to make speculations.

What I wanted to ask is if I'm on the right path and possibly a hint for point 2 where I'm going totally blind, I guess point 2 is inherited from solving point 1, so if my method is wrong I wont make much progress. I need to do this using Photoshop, I think just to make things more complicated.

Comment: You only have to make 2 rounded rectangles then make a pattern. IMHO using photoshop for this is the wrong tool. But ok ypu can do it.

Comment: @joojaa I see where you are going, this way would be easy to swap and control the colors, it looks more like a rounded square in a rectangular background, my only concern is how to align it properly? It starts with black/yellow and ends yellow/black.

Comment: Has to be done in Photoshop? Dead easy task in Illustrator - which is what I'd use.

Comment: @Scott yes, probably for that due reason, I've posted what I did to pass step 2 I have added a two-shaped logo, as it doesnt matter to be a real one; now stuck on point 4 what would be considered an improvement?

Comment: Sorry, what may or may not be an "improvement" all a matter of *opinion*. Seems kind of like a poorly planned assignment if it teaches you to use applications which are not ideal for the task at hand. `:)`.

Comment: Its not actually any harder to do in PS than illustrator. Its a bit waseful to do this in PS, since you can get a size independent result. Anyway this then raises a question: What is using PS? If a illustrator file is liked in PS is it PS. By forcing PS one loses at the point if tgis ever needs to be printed.

Comment: @joojaa out of curiosity, why there is a loss in printing from PS files if both are made as vector graphic?

Comment: @S.Redrum Because Photoshop does not know how to do patterns as vector graphics (so no resizing if paper size/aspect changes ). Also it does not know how to do a lot of other vector things either. So for example all raster graphics have the same pixel pitch in PS. This is not true in indesign or illustrator. Also PS makes handling big amount of vectors (needed for vectror graphics)  hard, And last but least its easy to make rasters out of your vectors without thinking that they are rasterized on output. PS all the answers here give you a raster solution :P

Comment: I know a lot of people would love to work only in PS. but really it is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a homework, no full receipes, only some hints!

**PART1 after the question was initialized to readable state:**

Your own version isn't good enough - not at least if I was a paying customer who wants an exact replica, but in high resolution.

- the black dots should be rounded except at the edges
- the yellow area is contiguous, there is room between the black dots.

Having only one layer it's difficult to control two colors fully independently. Have a solid yellow background and insert black dots to the second layer. Then it's easier also to control the edges of the black dots.

If you have perfect checkerboard with rectangular dots, you can for ex. select the black parts with a refined selection and copy them to a new layer to get rounded ones.

Then you can insert new solid yellow layer. Both new layers can have their own Hue&Saturation adjustment layers, activate the "only the next layer switch" and "colorize" in the adjustment dialogs. Here the rounded black dots are made blue and the yellow background is converted to orange:

[image]

Comment: I was able to change the colors but both or just the yellow, I still cant change for example the black dots added by the filter, is filter a good path to follow or should I discard it? When I saw this squared grid I went straight to `Halftone Pattern` filter as it looked simple enough but now I see there is no control over the black dots, I can add a colored layer on top of it and change blend mode, but this will change both black and yellow into something new, really can't be controlled.

Comment: wow this is a more elegant solution, just noticed you have added a picture!

Comment: Do not say this elegant, it's the brute force way.

Comment: sort of, but wanted to be kind for all the help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is just a partial answer since only solve point 2. where I was stuck at. I premise that I'm not sure if it is considered a correct approach but it worked. Probably there are better ways of doing that, here is what I have achieved, I can now control both colors in a really simple way:

[image: Current Result]

First I resolved the issue of connected squares, someone on my same stage suggested to have used brightness control layer and this did the trick. How I resolved the issue of black squares; my picture now have 3 layers, the bottom one is yellow with `Normal` blend, the middle one is the same pattern with black squares and `Linear Burn` blend. What did the trick was the top layer that is a `Fill Layer` I have then copied the second layer into the first layer mask and inverted it.

[image: Layers]

Since the mask content is inverted respect the level below I'm "painting" in coincidence of the second layer black tiles. To control the colors I just need to change the `Fill Layer` color and the bottom layer color :)