# Did I obtain a Lang Stereotest with photoshop or just bad eyes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

While working on my assignment ([Solving problems with a given illustration, how do I proceed?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/127097/solving-problems-with-a-given-illustration-how-do-i-proceed)) and experimenting I came to this image which ideally recalled Lang Stereotest images:

[image]

I'm not sure if everyone can see the effect or it is just me being visually impaired in some way, but to me it looks like the text is detached from the background. While I got to this casually experiementing with colors and blends. Is there a methodic way of achieving a Lang Stereotest image form any image, not necessarily using black & white only?

Comment: your example image is not black & white, it does give a 3D "volume" effect to me.

Comment: @Luciano as saying not necessarily black & white, is there a rule of thumb to obtain this effect using other colors? Like using colors in `Split Complementary` or `Triadic` harmonies starting from the background/dots color?

Comment: But anyway this doesn't look like a Lang Stereotest... those _are_ usually B&W https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0984/9292/files/LANG-STEREOPAD_Instructions_V3.0_English_Brochure_20_pages_final_version.pdf?12006842419194239978